# Why is Python Preinstalled on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, python

Why is Python Preinstalled on Ubuntu?

- Does the operating system depend on Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at 20.04, the technical reason is that `ubuntu-minimal` depends on `python3`.  It would be tough to run Ubuntu without `ubuntu-minimal` as its description is

> This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu minimal
> system, that is a functional command-line system with the following
> capabilities:
>
> - Boot
> - Detect hardware
> - Connect to a network
> - Install packages
> - Perform basic diagnostics
>
> It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended
> that it not be removed.

While I expect most of the core Linux programs don't require python, I believe a lot of software that Ubuntu (Canonical) writes is done in python.  Things like `ubuntu-advantage`, `landscape`, `cloud-init`, and `netplan`.

Another common dependency is that there are python `apt` libraries used by a number of packages.  For example, `unattended-upgrades` is written in python

Comment: You are right, Canonical likes python.

Answer (score 9):

Try running:

```
apt-cache rdepends python | grep -v python | wc -l
```

Since Ubuntu 20.04 uses python3 for default, run:

```
apt-cache rdepends python3 | grep -v python | wc -l
```

This basically says "Count the number of packages that depend on Python, **NOT** counting python specific packages". On my system it's well over 1000 other packages - safe to say Ubuntu depends pretty heavily on Python.

Comment: One of the dependencies is goldeneye and quick search pop ups saying that's a DoS tool. hmmmm. Maybe it's best to uninstall python after all!

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere there are hundreds of similar tools available in apt's sources. They can be used nefariously of course, but they also have legitimate uses for pentesters and other network security people.

Comment: Seems ubuntu server has tons of preinstalled goodies. :)

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere I'm guessing that's sarcasm, but just in case: the [GitHub page](https://github.com/jseidl/GoldenEye) says it is a HTTP DoS test tool and that it's meant to be used for security testing purposes only (wink-wink, nudge-nudge).

Comment: Output is 0 for me. Mmm...

Comment: @el-banto: I guess you are using 20.04 release, you have to replace python with python3  when running the command.

Comment: Doesn't this count all packages instead of just the ones installed on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu works with python, and without python Ubuntu won't work (actually, I never tested it, but I think it won't work). That's why it's already installed when you load Ubuntu.