# Why does Ubuntu use Python despite the fact that Python is an interpreted language?

Tags: python, java, c++, c

Interpreted languages like Python are generally slower than compared to C/C++ or Java. Are there any scientific reasons for Ubuntu to opt Python instead of other programming languages like C/C++ or Java?

My intention is not to have an opiniated answer. I just want the facts.

P.S. I'm not a programmer. I was learning about various types of programming languages and I got to know about this disadvantage. So, try answering in  layman's terms.

Comment: For scripts which are executed only once performance doesn't matter that much / it doesn't have a big impact

Comment: Ubuntu is not the one that decided this. It is generic Linux that uses python; well almost all; there are a few that do not install it by default. 1st time I ever see someone post that JAVA is fast :-X

Comment: 1 thing in favor of python: it is easier to read than any other language I code in.

Answer (score 2):

#### Python's readability makes the code *accessible* and *maintainable*

Volunteers in an open-source environment need to be able to easily read the code:

- It makes on-ramping volunteers easier.
- It makes drive-by contributions and patches more likely.
- It makes volunteer prototyping and testing simpler and more widespread.

The Question left out an important caveat: "*Interpreted languages like Python are generally slower than compared to C/C++ or Java* **at some tasks**."

- It's not slower at some tasks, too.
- Since the speed of humans is so much slower than either compiled or scripted software, often that speed difference (if any) is irrelevant to the user.

There is absolutely nothing preventing any volunteer or group from re-implementing most Python script using another compiled code to take advantage of that code's advantages; there's just little interest from volunteers in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Ubuntu uses Python heavily (and it's not only Ubuntu, many other Linux distributions use it too). But it is not true that it does not use / depend on other languages, C/C++ for example: the visible difference is that a program written in C can be compiled and then it no longer needs *the compiler*, but it still needs glibc, the GNU C runtime library. For Python programs the "runtime library" is the interpreter itself (sort of).

But also: yes, programs in Python are frequently slower than programs in C (Java, ...). But: a) when e.g. network communication or user interaction is involved, there is no need to write heavily optimized programs, any speedup is lost elsewhere; b) you have to choose - you can write heavily optimized programs, or you can write programs that are extremely portable, with considerably shorter code, therefore faster to develop and easier to maintain. If lightning speed is not among your top priorities, Python might be an excellent choice.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Ubuntu opts Python"? Ubuntu itself does not favor any particular language. It is shipped with the default support of some popular languages, like Java with OpenJDK, C++ with GCC, and Python with Python3 interpreter.

There is a number of reasons that developers consider when picking up a language for a particular task. Speed is not always the most important one. Sometimes it is about the ease of prototyping, portability, 3rd party extensions, popularity. Ubuntu offers tools that allow users work on their programming problems regardless of their priorites.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259446/1103140) for understanding what I mean by "Ubuntu opts Python".